# Detecting Touches outside UIView subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm modulating an app I'm making.  I want my subview to detect touches at any location on screen either to the left or right.  Now that it is a subview, I'm only able to detect touches within its bounds.  I tried changing the bounds of my subview, but that causes the subview to disappear from the screen completely.  Can my touch location be detected outside my subview?

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

    if(touchLocation.x < self.center.x) //touches occur to the left
    {
        right = false;
    }

    if(touchLocation.x > self.center.x) //touches occur to the right
    {
        right = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your *subview* is the view which **implement the code to intercept the touch**, you can intercept touches **just on that view**.

If you want intercept touch **out of the subview**, you **must** (**and is conceptually right**) add the intercept code in your *superview*.

Answer (score 0):

A gesture recognizer could work for your situation, depending on what your trying to pick up on.  If your situation fits you can add one to the subviews window.  You can access it via your views window property.  Then inside of your gesture recognizer code you can use the "Hit testing in a view" and "Converting between view coordinates" methods of UIView to find out if the touch was in your view.  Be sure to remove the gesture recognizer from the window when your object is removed from the superview or it's dealloced.